# Fiz um Grafo e queria Listar ele mas em Lista Adjacente

Tags: c, c++, grafo

```
#include <iostream>
#define max 10
using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

struct Grafo{
    int matrizadj[max][max];
    int qtdVertiz,qtdAresta;
    char Visitador[max] = "";
    char PilhaAmigos[max] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'};
    Grafo *prox;
};

void IniciarGrafo(Grafo *grafo,int qtdVertiz) {
    grafo->qtdVertiz = qtdVertiz;
    grafo->qtdAresta = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= qtdVertiz; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= qtdVertiz; j++)
            grafo->matrizadj[i][j] = 0;
    }
    
    return;
    /*      A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J 
        A  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        B  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        C  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        D  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        E  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        F  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        G  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        H  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        I  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        J  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
    */
}


void InserirAresta(Grafo *grafo,int l,int c) {
    //l Linha //c Coluna
    if(grafo->matrizadj[l][c] == 1) {
        return;
    } else {
        grafo->matrizadj[l][c] = 1;
        grafo->qtdAresta = +1;
    }
}

int MostrarGrafo(Grafo *grafo) {
    cout << "    A B C D E F G H I J ";
    cout << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i <= grafo->qtdVertiz; i++) {
        cout << "\n";
        if(i == 0)
            cout << "A: ";
        if(i == 1)
            cout << "B: ";
        if(i == 2)
            cout << "C: ";
        if(i == 3)
            cout << "D: ";
        if(i == 4)
            cout << "E: ";
        if(i == 5)
            cout << "F: ";
        if(i == 6)
            cout << "G: ";
        if(i == 7)
            cout << "H: ";
        if(i == 8)
            cout << "I: ";
        if(i == 9)
            cout << "J: ";
        for(int j = 0; j <= grafo->qtdVertiz; j++)
            cout << " " << grafo->matrizadj[i][j];
    }
    
}

void MostarAmigos(Grafo *grafo) {

    for(int i = 0; i <= grafo->qtdVertiz; i++) {
        grafo->PilhaAmigos[i];
        for(int j = 0; j <= grafo->qtdVertiz; j++) {
            if(grafo->matrizadj[i][j] == 1) {
                grafo->Visitador[i] = + grafo->PilhaAmigos[j];
                
            }                       
        }       
    }
}

void Visitador(Grafo *grafo) {

    for(int i = 0; i <= grafo->qtdVertiz; i++) {
        cout << grafo->PilhaAmigos[i] << "->";
        for(int j = 0; j < grafo->qtdAresta; j++) {
            cout << grafo->Visitador[i];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
bool BuscaProfunda(Grafo *grafo, int l,int c) {
    if(grafo->matrizadj[l][c] == 1)
        return true; // tem caminho
    else
        return false;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Grafo grafo;
    IniciarGrafo(&grafo,max-1);
    InserirAresta(&grafo,1,1);
    InserirAresta(&grafo,1,3);
    InserirAresta(&grafo,3,4);
    InserirAresta(&grafo,7,9);
    MostrarGrafo(&grafo);
    cout << "\n\n";
    MostarAmigos(&grafo);
    Visitador(&grafo);
    cout << BuscaProfunda(&grafo,7,9);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045)

Answer (score -2):

Queria Armazenar Char, ou Seja ele iria Armazenar Caracteres, parei Pra Pensar Refiz

```
#include <iostream>
#define max 10

struct 
Grafo{
    int matrizadj[max][max];
    int qtdVertiz,qtdAresta;
    string Visitador[max] ;
    string PilhaAmigos[max] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"};
    Grafo *prox;
};

void IniciarGrafo(Grafo *grafo,int qtdVertiz) {
    grafo->qtdVertiz = qtdVertiz;
    grafo->qtdAresta = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= qtdVertiz; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j <= qtdVertiz; j++)
            grafo->matrizadj[i][j] = 0;
    }
    
    return;
    /*      A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J 
        A  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        B  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        C  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        D  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        E  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        F  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        G  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        H  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        I  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
        J  [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0] [0]
    */
}


void InserirAresta(Grafo *grafo,int l,int c) {
    //l Linha //c Coluna
    if(grafo->matrizadj[l][c] == 1) {
        return;
    } else {
        grafo->matrizadj[l][c] = 1;
        grafo->qtdAresta = +1;
    }
}

int MostrarGrafo(Grafo *grafo) {
    cout << "    A B C D E F G H I J ";
    cout << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i <= grafo->qtdVertiz; i++) {
        cout << "\n";
        if(i == 0)
            cout << "A: ";
        if(i == 1)
            cout << "B: ";
        if(i == 2)
            cout << "C: ";
        if(i == 3)
            cout << "D: ";
        if(i == 4)
            cout << "E: ";
        if(i == 5)
            cout << "F: ";
        if(i == 6)
            cout << "G: ";
        if(i == 7)
            cout << "H: ";
        if(i == 8)
            cout << "I: ";
        if(i == 9)
            cout << "J: ";
        for(int j = 0; j <= grafo->qtdVertiz; j++)
            cout << " " << grafo->matrizadj[i][j];
    }
    
}

void MostarAmigos(Grafo *grafo) {

    for(int i = 0; i <= grafo->qtdVertiz; i++) {
        grafo->PilhaAmigos[i];
        for(int j = 0; j <= grafo->qtdVertiz; j++) {
            if(grafo->matrizadj[i][j] == 1) {
        
                grafo->Visitador[i] +=  grafo->PilhaAmigos[j];
            }                       
        }       
    }
}

void Visitador(Grafo *grafo) {

    for(int i = 0; i <= grafo->qtdVertiz; i++) {
        cout << grafo->PilhaAmigos[i] << "->";
        for(int j = 0; j < grafo->qtdAresta; j++) {
            cout << grafo->Visitador[i];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
bool BuscaProfunda(Grafo *grafo, int l,int c) {
    if(grafo->matrizadj[l][c] == 1)
        return true; // tem caminho
    else
        return false;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Grafo grafo;
    IniciarGrafo(&grafo,max-1);
    InserirAresta(&grafo,1,1);
    InserirAresta(&grafo,1,3);
    InserirAresta(&grafo,3,4);
    InserirAresta(&grafo,7,9);
    MostrarGrafo(&grafo);
    cout << "\n\n";
    MostarAmigos(&grafo);
    Visitador(&grafo);
    cout << BuscaProfunda(&grafo,7,9);
    return 0;
}
```